# Error 1452: Cannot add or update child row

Tags: mysql

Error 1452: Cannot update or add child row. I met all the requirements of the foreign key but still an error is occurring. Can anyone help me out with this issue.

Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
Executing:
INSERT INTO `ram`.`attendance` (`course_id`, `student_id`, `number_of_days_present`, `number_of_days_absent`) VALUES ('1638', '1000', '25', '5');
INSERT INTO `ram`.`attendance` (`course_id`, `student_id`, `number_of_days_present`, `number_of_days_absent`) VALUES ('1639', '1001', '26', '4');
INSERT INTO `ram`.`attendance` (`course_id`, `student_id`, `number_of_days_present`, `number_of_days_absent`) VALUES ('1637', '1002', '27', '3');

ERROR 1452: 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ram`.`attendance`, CONSTRAINT `course_id` FOREIGN KEY (`course_id`) REFERENCES `course` (`course_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)
SQL Statement:
INSERT INTO `ram`.`attendance` (`course_id`, `student_id`, `number_of_days_present`, `number_of_days_absent`) VALUES ('1638', '1000', '25', '5')

ERROR 1452: 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ram`.`attendance`, CONSTRAINT `course_id` FOREIGN KEY (`course_id`) REFERENCES `course` (`course_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)
SQL Statement:
INSERT INTO `ram`.`attendance` (`course_id`, `student_id`, `number_of_days_present`, `number_of_days_absent`) VALUES ('1639', '1001', '26', '4')

ERROR 1452: 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ram`.`attendance`, CONSTRAINT `course_id` FOREIGN KEY (`course_id`) REFERENCES `course` (`course_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)
SQL Statement:
INSERT INTO `ram`.`attendance` (`course_id`, `student_id`, `number_of_days_present`, `number_of_days_absent`) VALUES ('1637', '1002', '27',

Comment: Depending on what language or API you are using, you may or may not be able to do multiple queries inside a single statement. (For instance, mysqli_query() in PHP does NOT allow that.) It looks like your initial insertion contains 3 insertions separated by a semi-colon.

Comment: Does your `course` table have rows with `course_id` of '1638', '1639', and '1637'?

Comment: Yes they do have it.

Comment: Please re-check, making sure you are looking at the right column in the right table. Check using a tool like phpMyAdmin rather than within your application to prevent possible bugs.

Comment: check that your `course_id` INDEX is actually made up of the `course_id` COLUMN in both tables.

Comment: I'm able to insert values into the 'course' table but not into the 'attendance' table. Does this clue help us in figuring out the problem??

Comment: You wrote "yes, they do have it." Please go back USING PHPMYADMIN and look at your COURSE table and confirm whether THAT table has rows with those course_id. It would set my mind at ease if you would actually take a screenshot of that and post it on a fiddle somewhere and link to it here.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `attendance` (
`course_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`student_id` int(11) NOT NULL,`number_of_days_present` decimal(5,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`number_of_days_absent` decimal(5,0) DEFAULT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (`course_id`,`student_id`), KEY `student_id_idx` `student_id`,`course_id`),CONSTRAINT `course_id` FOREIGN KEY (`course_id`) REFERENCES `course` (`course_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,CONSTRAINT `student_id` FOREIGN KEY (`student_id`) REFERENCES `student_details` (`student_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1640 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Answer (score 1):

Your database is set up that you cannot insert a row into the `attendance` table unless it has an appropriate row (identified by the relevant `course_id`) in the table `course`.

It appears that your table `course` does not have rows with `course_id` of '1638', '1639', and '1637'.

If you add those records (with those course_id) then you should be able to add the records into `attendance` table.

Obviously your application has a problem because it should have checked this.